# How can I tell which pipeline triggered my pipeline in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working on an auditing pipeline (YAML) in Azure devops that needs to collect deployment logs and then upload them to a JIRA ticket.

We have a bunch of services with deployment pipelines (YAML) set up in Azure Devops.

I have a pipeline that is triggered by any one of these pipelines finishing. How can I tell which pipeline and which run of said pipeline triggered my pipeline?
Are there any environment variables I could use, or is there any way to get this information? I'd like to forward the pipeline ID and the run ID to a script I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $(Build.Reason) it holds the event that caused the build to run.

**Manual**: A user manually queued the build.

**IndividualCI**: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in.

**BatchedCI**: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in, and the Batch changes was selected.

**Schedule**: Scheduled trigger.

**ValidateShelveset**: A user manually queued the build of a specific TFVC shelveset.

**CheckInShelveset**: Gated check-in trigger.

**PullRequest**: The build was triggered by a Git branch policy that requires a build.

**ResourceTrigger**: The build was triggered by a resource trigger or it was triggered by another build.

If you added the triggering pipeline(s) as a resource(s) like

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyAlias  
    source: <Name of pipeline>
    trigger:    
      stages:         # Trigger when pipeline stage completed 
      - UAT # name of stage that triggers the pipeline to run
```

You can get info on the triggering pipeline like

```
stages
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
    
    - script: |
        echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
        echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.projectName)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.projectID)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.pipelineName)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.pipelineID)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.runName)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.runURI)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.sourceBranch)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.runID)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.sourceCommit)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.sourceProvider)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.requestedFor)
        echo $(resources.pipeline.MyAlias.requestedForID)
        echo $(Build.Repository.Git.SubmoduleCheckout)  
      displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

Comment: If you have multiple pipelines set up then you still need to figure out if "MyAlias" was triggered or another one.

Comment: you can be specific about which pipeline you want to use via the source parameter to answer the above comment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines. the Alias is useful in situations where you have more than one pipeline (trigger) resource used

Comment: Is there a way i can retrieve the name from the ResourceTrigger pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up using this custom task:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks

Then I parameterized the task I'm triggering with $(Build.BuildId) and $(System.DefinitionId) found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I would suggest marking the other answer as accepted. It helped me out and doesn't use any external libs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing, and found on the documentation what needed:

**Resources.TriggeringAlias** -> *returns the name of the pipeline resource, such as source-pipeline from the previous example.*

So if you have a pipeline that will be triggered by multiple resources based on this variable you will retrieve the alias name of that triggering pipeline.

Link to documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines